# How is the 'Block User' list sorted/presented?

Tags: facebook

So I've had to block a few Users on FB. This was awhile ago - some as long as half-a-year in the past.

Recently FB recommended a 'You may know' with whom I share acquaintances. This 'You may know' recommended profile was fishy ... I preemptively 'Block'ed this 'You may know' profile. Whereupon FB took me to the 'Manage Blocking' page.

To my consternation the 'You may know' profile appeared in the middle of the 'Block Users' list. In my experience a 'Block'ed profile appears at the top  of the 'Block Users' ... My guess is an existing name in the Block'ed list changed.

How is the 'Block User' list sorted/presented?
Am I seeing a name in the 'Block User' list/profile change?

Comment: Reverse order of blocking (most recently blocked listed first)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how the list you looked at was sorted. According to Facebook, a person changing their profile name is not enough to escape your block list. They'd need to create a new profile OR have your Facebook password so they could log in as you and unblock themselves.

For those reasons, what you saw would not be caused by a blocked person suddenly showing up on your "You may know" list.

You could do your own experiment by creating a FB profile, having it friend one of your existing friends, block the profile, change the name on the profile, and see if it shows up on your "you may know" list. It won't.

Comment: I have a niggling suspicion they sort it by emailID rather than the profileID itself ...

Answer (score -3):

I believe the block list is sorted by how many times the blocked user looks at your account.  So if you block your best friend or family member that has viewed your profile with a high frequency they will appear at the top of the list.  If you block someone that didn't care about your profile in the first place they will appear at the bottom of your list.

Comment: Do you have any documentation to back that up?